# kies update SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.exe.cab version 2.1.1.1124_17

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is this Kies update taking too long?](https://superuser.com/questions/373011/why-is-this-kies-update-taking-too-long)

I have been updating my Samsung kies for the past 6 hours.  The file size for the update was indicated as 65424 kb. I have already done 1170000kb plus and still counting and the update is still ongoing although the system indicates 100%.  What should i do?

Comment: [Why is this Kies update taking too long?](http://superuser.com/q/373011)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting the transfer?
You might have issues with a security program that is conflicting with the update.
Try disabling antivirus, firewall etc.